# How can I have an agenda timeline view of multiple files?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm using org-mode as a knowledge base, where each file is for a specific project that I'm working on.

Each file has its own journal and I would love to see an aggregated journal of all the things I've done.

That information is in a bunch of `.org` files in a specific directory.

The functionality I'm looking for is what the agenda timeline provides, but it only works for one file.

Is there a way to make it work for all files in `org-agenda-files`?

Comment: This seems a duplicate to the question [`Timelineview of all agenda files`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47861/timelineview-of-all-agenda-files) on `unix.SE`.

Comment: You are right. Will there be an effort to try to migrate emacs questions from other SO? (I dont know if that is possible. I could help with said effort)

Comment: [Emacs questions from Stack Overflow or Super User](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4/emacs-questions-from-stack-overflow-or-super-user) is, I think, the official policy on duplicate questions and migration.

IMO, that other question is fine for migrating here since it's borderline on `unix.SE` and could probably get a better answer here.

Comment: @purple_arrows Regardless of policy, the question that elemakil linked to can't be migrated because it is *way* [older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/244644).

Comment: @itsjeyd Doh!  Of course.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the suggestions provided in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55864/16894), the following command collects the contents of all `org-agenda-files` in a single file and then calls the `org-agenda` command that builds the timeline:

```el
(defun org-agenda-timeline-all (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (dolist (org-agenda-file org-agenda-files)
      (insert-file-contents org-agenda-file nil)
      (end-of-buffer)
      (newline))
    (write-file "/tmp/timeline.org")
    (org-agenda arg "L")))
```

For best results, set up a custom key binding for this command via

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c t") 'org-agenda-timeline-all)
```

**Additionally**, if you want the command to consider all `org-mode` files that are currently open (in addition your `org-agenda-files`, which may or may not be open), you can replace `org-agenda-files` with a call to `(org-files-list)` in the code above.

Comment: the problem with using org-agenda-files, is that if it is a directory, the code wont work.

Comment: @lal00 - replace `org-agenda-files` with `(org-agenda-files t)` to solve that problem.

Comment: The other problem with this approach is that you lack the reference back to the original .org file. I want to both know where a particular completed task came from, and also be able to navigate to that .org (or its archive) file.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't quite identical to the timeline, but you can make a custom agenda view showing some time span in "log mode".  By binding `org-agenda-files` locally in the the agenda command we can load whatever files we want without messing up the normal behavior.  This does a week, change `org-agenda-span` to the number of days you want.

```
(defvar org-timeline-files nil
  "The files to be included in `org-timeline-all-files'. Follows
  the same rules as `org-agenda-files'")

(setq org-timeline-files '("/path/to/org/files/"))

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("R" "Week in review"
                agenda ""
                ;; agenda settings
                ((org-agenda-span 'week)
                  (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 0) ;; start on Sunday
                  (org-agenda-overriding-header "Week in Review")
                  (org-agenda-files 
                    (let ((org-agenda-files org-timeline-files))
                          (org-agenda-files nil 'ifmode)))
                  (org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t)
                  (org-agenda-log-mode-items '(clock state))
                  (org-agenda-archives-mode t) ; include archive files
                )))
```